# Add/Remove Select Box Not Giving Values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

(The question is at the bottom of this post)

Hello, I am following this [tutorial](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/create-add-remove-select-lists-using-jquery/).

I have made 3 boxes total, 1 with all the values and 2 to separate the values.

Like this picture shows :

[image]

This is my Jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#and").click(function() {
            $("#totalselect option:selected").each(function() {
            $("#select-and").append("<option value='" + $(this).val() + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
            $(this).remove();
            });
        });
        $("#removeand").click(function() {
            $("#select-and option:selected").each(function() {
            $("#totalselect").append("<option value='" + $(this).val() + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
            $(this).remove();
            });
        });
        $("#or").click(function() {
            $("#totalselect option:selected").each(function() {
            $("#select-or").append("<option value='" + $(this).val() + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
            $(this).remove();
            });
        });
        $("#removeor").click(function() {
            $("#select-or option:selected").each(function() {
            $("#totalselect").append("<option value='" + $(this).val() + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
            $(this).remove();
            });
        });
        });
    </script>
```

And this is my HTML :

```
<div id="mass_options">
        <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="and">And</a>
        <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="or">Or</a>
        <select name="totalselect[]" id="totalselect" multiple size="5">
            <?php foreach ($reasons as $r) { ?>
                <option value="reason_<?php echo $r['reason_id'] ?>">Reason: <?php echo $r['reason'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php foreach ($options5 as $key => $value) { ?>
                <option value="status_<?php echo $key ?>">Session Status: <?php echo $value ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php foreach ($info as $key => $value) { ?>
                <option value="action_<?php echo $key ?>">Action: <?php echo $value ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        </div>

        <select name="and" id="select-and" multiple size="5" class="selectnew">
        </select>
        <select name="or" id="select-or" multiple size="5" class="selectnew">
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="removeand">Remove And</a>
        <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="removeor">Remove Or</a>
```

**The issue**

When I click Next it sends me to a page that just does a var_dump of all the post values, what I am noticing is what ever I add to the "and box" or the "or box" is not in the var_dump as a value. The only way I can get it to be submitted (when I click next) is actually highlighting the value in the "and box" or in the "or box". How can I have it so, if it is in either the "and box" or the "or box" that it is automatically selected for me to submit to my script without me having to highlight them?

The reason why I am doing it like this is so I can dynamically build a query with Where clauses being "AND" or "OR" so I can make emailing students a lot more dynamic rather then just cut and dry.

Any help would be great.

Comment: That's not [tag:html], that's [tag:php]. There's a difference, please show the actual HTML that's seen by the browser *after* it's been processed/sent by the PHP script.

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter, so in my case I query the database for all reasons, statuses, and actions and have a foreach over the the returned values. This is my entire portion of the html. The results of that "php script" as you call it, are that screen shot I showed you all above.

Comment: And I think it is HTML when I am using html tags, I just embedded php foreach loops so I wouldn't have to write 60+ values manually. And then if the values in the database change I would have to change the HTML options x amount of times. That is why I am using php to do all the heavy lifting for me to dynamically add my values that I need from my database.

Comment: Dude, when can not easily _test_ your code if it includes dynamic PHP code, because we are missing the data and the framework around it. _You_ however should be able to do “View page source code” in your browser, and copy&paste that somewhere, and create for example a http://jsfiddle.net/ demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Sorry I did not think of that.

Comment: Question gets closed "cannot be reasonably answered in its current form" but some one has already given me a great answer... StackOverFlow is hilarious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a native form submit you have to "highlight" your options. You know only selected options will be send in the post. You can select them with jQuery before sending data:

```
$("form *:submit").click(function() { /* choose a better selector for submit button */
    $("#select-and options, #select-or options").attr("selected", true);
    $(this).parents("form:first").submit();
});
```

Another alternative without "autoselect" is to send the post with AJAX. In this way you can prepare your sending data.

..or edit your jQuery to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#and").click(function() {
            $("#totalselect option:selected").appendTo("#select-and");
        });
        $("#or").click(function() {
            $("#totalselect option:selected").appendTo("#select-or");
        });
        $("#removeand").click(function() {
            $("#select-and option:selected")
                .removeAttr("selected")
                .appendTo("#totalselect");
        });
        $("#removeor").click(function() {
            $("#select-or option:selected")
                .removeAttr("selected")
                .appendTo("#totalselect");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Right I have selected them... look at my Jquery for "#and" and "#or" I'm not a jquery guru but I think those lines mean that I am selecting those values.

Comment: you append option elements only with a value-attribute! selected-attribute is missing!

Comment: totalselect option:selected

Comment: My option:selected is not missing though? And I just tried you answer and still, I get nothing posted to the next page.

Comment: It shows in my Jquery about 4 or 5 lines down, option:selected is there.

Comment: i chose the wrong selector for your select-elements i edited my answer

Comment: This is almost working, now I only get one value posted from each box. So if I have two in "and" and two in "or" only one from each will be posted. Not all of them

Comment: Your awesome, and I am sorry for doing this, but now when I do "removeand" or "removeor" the value goes back into the main select dropdown (like it should) but it doesn't get un-selected. So when I hit the submit button (next) the value is selected, and it shouldn't be...

Comment: see in edited version: .removeAttr("selected")

Comment: Absolutely wonderful. Thank you so very much. Expect a +50 coming your way when I can put a bounty on this answer.

Comment: doesnt matter... i like bulls, too

Comment: Huh? lol bulls? What you mean?

Comment: HAHA! Yea I love em :D I made an edit to your answer. Take a look at it :)