# Dynamic PDO Query - With AND / OR

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, pdo

I have two issues, the first as the title states is that I need to have dynamic query with AND/OR in it. I fully understand the AND part (I've done a bunch of these) however, the OR part is very confusing to me because looking at this following sql :

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1
```

then if you add an OR statement if a condition is met :

```
if(isset($_POST['OR'])){
   $sql. = " OR peaches = :good";
}
```

then the query will return WHERE 1 OR peaches =  :good

Again I understand the part with the AND, but I do not understand how to set up the OR part.

[This is how I have set up the AND / OR selection (and this works)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377718/add-remove-select-box-not-giving-values)

The second issue I am facing is this code snippet from the same script (please read code comments) :

```
$sql .= " GROUP BY anum"; // I always group BY anum no matter what

if ($count !== "") { // if COUNT is not "" 
    $sql .= " HAVING COUNT(session.anum) :count"; // Then I want the user to be able to choose the operator (> < => =< =) and the dynamic number for it to use
    $placeholder[':count'] = $count; // Then add the key :count to an array with the value of $count 
}
$dynamic = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
$dynamic->execute($placeholder);
```

So as you notice I give the named parameter **(:count)** the value of $count, however this does "not work".

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do (`$sql .= " HAVING COUNT(session.anum) :count";`)

If not then I could just do :  `$sql .= " HAVING COUNT(session.anum) $count";`

but that would defeat the purpose of PDO.

Any help would be great

Comment: Yor `having` statement misses an operator for comparison...

Comment: $count as the operator + the number

Comment: Right, but no errors are shown?

Answer (score 2):

**Problem 1:**
The reason that some developers use `WHERE 1` when they have optional search terms is that an expression like `TRUE AND <condition>` is always equal to `<condition>`.  This is basic boolean algebra.

But this is not the case for `OR` expressions.  `TRUE OR <condition>` is always simply `TRUE`.  You could modify your base query to use `WHERE 0` so that when you append an `OR` term it comes out as `WHERE 0 OR <condition>`.  Any expression like `FALSE OR <condition>` is always equal to the `<condition>`.

If you need to support both `AND` and `OR` in the same SQL query, you need to start putting parentheses around terms so they evaluate in the way you intend.  I'm not going to explain [boolean algebra](https://www.google.com/search?q=boolean%20algebra%20tutorial) and [MySQL's operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operator-precedence.html) in this StackOverflow answer.  But suffice to say that simply appending terms with `.=` isn't going to work when you have a mix of `AND` and `OR` terms.

**Problem 2:**
Parameters are very useful, but they don't solve every case of dynamic SQL.  You can use an SQL parameter in place of a *single literal value*, but nothing else.

- Not table names
- Not column names
- Not lists of values (like an `IN( )` predicate)
- Not SQL keywords
- Not expressions
- Not operators

You have to use string interpolation to include a user-chosen operator in your HAVING clause.

It's recommended to use *whitelisting* to avoid risk of SQL injection when you need to interpolate dynamic content and can't use a parameter.

Comment: I'm reading up on string interpolation. As for the whitelisting I feel like checking the variable $count to see if it contains anything other then the 5 operators and digits from 1 - 10 should suffice for a whitelist so I could add the variable to the query after the HAVING clause, no?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine.  As long as you filter the input so it can't contain anything you don't expect.

Comment: Great thanks. When I finish up here I'll accept your answer and update OP

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue, what is the problem exactly?

For the second, [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) says that you can't use functions on `having` clauses.
You can do like this:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(session.anum) AS total GROUP BY session.anum HAVING total > :count
```

Comment: You can in fact use expressions including aggregate functions or scalar functions in the HAVING clause.  The manual refers to using group-ambiguous expressions when `SQL_MODE=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is in effect.